# The incorrect parameter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run below code getting this error without even running the code:

> System error: The parameter is incorrect

This code formats the shape and then calls for another code. When I assigned it to a shape and try to run it is showing the error without even running the code. I wrote exactly similar code in another file and it worked. What might be the mistake here?

```
Sub Supplier2()

With Worksheets("Evolution")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

.Shapes("Arrow: Affiliate").Visible = msoFalse
.Shapes("Arrow: Brand").Visible = msoFalse
.Shapes("Arrow: Supplier").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("Arrow: SnP_Planner").Visible = msoFalse
.Shapes("Arrow: Code").Visible = msoFalse


.Shapes("Affiliate").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("Brand").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("Supplier").Visible = msoFalse
.Shapes("SnP_Planner").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("Code").Visible = msoCTrue

.Range("U3").Value = "Supplier Location"

Call Defaulters_Evol

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: **"I wrote exactly similar code in another file and it worked."**
Why don't you use that file instead then?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was just trying to find the issue